# WPF Access Object from Binding Expression

Tags: c#, xaml, datacontext

I'm having trouble accessing the true object behind a Datacontext binding expression.

The parent canvas has a DataContext defined in code to a dictionary(string/object (Bindetails):

I have the following XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="100" Height="90" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
  <Rectangle Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1" Width="95" Height="80" Fill="White"/>
  <Canvas x:Name="Frame" DataContext="{Binding [Frame]}">
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1" Width="1.75" Height="80" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="2.75" Canvas.Top="79.25" Width="92.5" Height="1.75" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="94.25" Canvas.Top="1" Width="1.75" Height="80" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="2.75" Canvas.Top="42.5" Width="72" Height="1.75" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="74.75" Canvas.Top="1" Width="1.75" Height="78.25" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
  </Canvas>
  <Canvas x:Name="_1_1" Width="5.375" Height="40" Tag="1-1" DataContext="{Binding [1-1]}">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="2.75" Y="2"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="5.375" Height="40" Fill="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="0.125" Stroke="#000000"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="3" Foreground="#000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">1-1</TextBlock>
  </Canvas>
.
.
.
```

My question is how would I go about accessing the DataContext binding from the code side? I'm iterating through the parent Canvas's children like so:

```
private void EnumElementChildren (DependencyObject parent)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {                
                DependencyObject childVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);             
                if (childVisual is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    FrameworkElement instance = (FrameworkElement)childVisual;
                    if (instance != null)
                    {

                        if (instance.GetBindingExpression(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty) != null)
                        {
                        //Access data bound object here


                        }
```

Any insight on this would be  greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit**

I explored the BindingExpression object and inside the parentbinding I am able to retrieve the path. (example being the first child with binding "Frame"). I'm not able to see a reference to the actual object. Is it necessary to trace the parents up until you get a datasource object (with a recursive function)?